# How to display some folder properties under it?

Tags: java, zk, zul

I'm making an inbox widget and i need to show the Email of the sender and the Date under each folder in the inbox widget.

this is a part of the code

```
'''
<div children="@bind(vm.displayedFolders)" if="${vm.isEmpty}">
        <template name="children" var="folders">
           <div> 
              <label value="${folders}" sclass="inbox-widget-label"/>
           </div>
        </template>
     </div>
'''
```

and this is the java code

```
 private void initDisplayedFolders() {
  displayedFolders = new ArrayList<>();

  for (final CmisObject child : inboxFolder.getChildren()) {
     if (displayedFolders.size() >= NUMBER_OF_FOLDERS_TO_DISPLAY) {
        break;
     }
     if (child instanceof Folder) {
        final Folder childFolder = (Folder) child;
        for (final CmisObject grandChild : childFolder.getChildren()) {
           if (displayedFolders.size() >= NUMBER_OF_FOLDERS_TO_DISPLAY) {
              break;
           } else {
              displayedFolders.add(grandChild.getName());
           }
        }
     }
  }
  if (!displayedFolders.isEmpty()) {
     isEmpty = true;
  }
```

}

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The java codes looks like initialize `displayedFolders` with a collections of folder names. The zul will create a list of folder label in vertical order if any.

They both looks fine. So I don't see any problems. Could tell me what is not you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, it looks like you can just:

```xml
    <div children="@bind(vm.displayedFolders)" if="${vm.isEmpty}">
        <template name="children" var="folders">
           <div> 
              <label value="${folders}" sclass="inbox-widget-label"/>
              <label value="@init(vm.sender)" />
              <label value="@init(vm.date)" />
           </div>
        </template>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I managed to solve it with a Listbox , Three entries in each cell